# Objective-C UITabBarItem: Custom Icon Color for All States with UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I want my tab bar item to have original icon colors in all states. I could not do it in IB so I managed to change them programmatically:

```
for (int i=0; i<[_tabBar.subviews count]; i++) {
    UITabBarItem * item = (UITabBarItem*)[_tabBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    item.image = image;
    //item.selectedImage = image; //CRASH :(
}
```

However, I am not able to set `item.selectedImage = image;`. This result s in crash. How to set it in selected image state and other states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the render mode of an image in a `.xcassets` folder.
[image]

Simply select "Original Image" from "Render as" in the attributes inspector. After you change that you can simply select the images you want for "Image" and "Selected image" in your storyboard for your Tab Bar Image. The image will appear gray in the storyboard but will render normally when your app runs.

It's very unusual to traverse a view hierarchy like you're doing.